# How can I force a VirtualHost in Apache to not listen for undefined subdomains on 443?

Tags: apache, https, virtualhost, httpd.conf

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/htdocs
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have a virtual host configured for `foo.example.com`, but that only listens on port 80.

I have the A record for foo.example.com pointing to this same server. If I visit `https://foo.example.com` in my browser, it loads the Virtual Host for `www.example.com`. How can I combat this?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have not setup the SSL for the sub domain `foo.example.com` and so it uses the `www.` domain. If you do not want SSL you can simply remove the Virtual Host all together running on port 443, otherwise just add to the configuration the following:

**Allow `foo.example.com` to operate on SSL**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName foo.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.example.com/htdocs
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**Redirect HTTPS to HTTP**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName foo.example.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.example.com
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://foo.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
        DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.example.com/htdocs
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**Or if you want a 404 Error then use:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName foo.example.com
        RewriteEngine on
        Redirect 404 /
        ErrorDocument 404 "Page Not Found"
        DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.example.com/htdocs
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Interesting. I do not want `https://foo.example.com` to resolve to anything – users should get a 404. What Virtual Host should I remove in that case?

Comment: Added even more solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, since I already have www.example.com listening on port 443, it takes precedence and I receive this error when reloading the Apache configuration: `VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence`